# trailing slash version of website gives 500 server error - how to redirect to non-trailing slash version

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have built a new custom designed website which is new, replacing an old wordpress website where every page had a trailing slash at the end of the url

I have added code in the .htaccess file in both root directory and sub-folders to remove .php file extension (which works fine) and redirect any traffic from version with trailing slash to version without trailing slash

However, especially in my "services" sub-folder this causes 404 errors or 500 server errors when I take the code out of htaccess, what I want is for the old pages to display without the trailing slash ideally, but having tried many ways I am having no luck

When I put in what is meant to be the correct code for this, it redirects the URL to a URL without the subfolder name and hence gives a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Should I try a different approach or am I just making a silly mistake?

here is my code from htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /services/



RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]


</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I added the following to redirect to non-trailing slash version:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Which causes the website to redirect to a URL without the sub-folder name obviously resulting in a 404 error

I have been going round in circles with this for a while so if someone could please suggest what I can do to redirect all traffic to trailing slash URL to Non-Trailing slash url (the version which exists) that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /services/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to remove `/` before `$1` in railing slash redirect rule as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have just replaced it but it still is trying to redirect to a URL without the subfolder name in it.. am I writing something in my code that is doing this? I replaced all of it with yours and still doing the same

Comment: yes, it wasn't redirecting before either, as I had taken the trailing slash rewrite out, it is only when I add something to re-write the trailing slash - it takes out the sub-domain folder name from the url and gives a 404, If i do not have a trailing slash re-write, it gives a 500 server error when I visit the version of the website with a trailing slash. Does that make sense? thanks for any suggestions, much appreciated

Comment: so the code I have written shouldn't cause the url to redirect to url without subfolder name? i.e when I add the rewrite rule to redirect to non-trailing slash version of website, the url redirects from website.com/subfolder/page1 to website.com/page1, the htaccess code shouldn't be doing this surely? Or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Your rule was stripping subfolder but my suggested rule won't do that if cache is cleared and your have correct `RewriteBase` directive there.

Comment: ah okay, I will try it again and clear cache again, is it the RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /services/ which is stripping the subfolder?

Comment: I cleared cache via chrome instead and it works!!!! Thank you so much, you are amazing, you have saved me hours, thank you :)